# Flask WTForms subforms and independent validating inside one common form

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, subform

I'm writing profile page and got some trouble with subforms in Flask.
For example - I have one page with 2 submit buttons and fields like - password and some notes.

**views.py**

```
@auth.route('/profile/<user>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def profile(user):
    form=ProfileForm()
    if request.method('POST'):
        if form.profile_password.sub_pass.data and form.profile_password.validate(form):
            db_rw("update users set password=? where username=?",(generate_password_hash(form.profile_password.password1.data), user))
            flash('Password has been updated')
        elif form.profile_notes.sub_info.data and form.profile_avatar.validate(form):
            db_rw("update users set notes=? where username=?",(form.profile_notes.notes.data, user))
            flash('Notes has been updatedd')
    return render_template('auth/profile.html', user=user, form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfilePasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    password1 = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=3,max=20,message='The password should be at least 8 characters long')]) #!!!!
    password2 = PasswordField('Repeat Password', validators=[EqualTo('password1',message='The passwords are mismatched')])
    sub_pass = SubmitField('Change')

class ProfileNotesForm(FlaskForm):
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes', validators=[Length(min=0, max=150)])
    sub_info = SubmitField('Save')

class ProfileAvatarForm(FlaskForm):
    ava = FileField('Avatar')
    sub_pic = SubmitField('Upload')

class ProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    profile_password=FormField(ProfilePasswordForm)
    profile_notes=FormField(ProfileNotesForm)
    profile_avatar=FormField(ProfileAvatarForm)
```

**profile.html**

```
{% block content %}

  <h3>Hello {{ user }} <br>


    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

  <div>
    Change password: <br>

    {{ form.profile_password.password1 }}<br>
         {% for error in form.profile_password.password1.errors  %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
         {% endfor %}           
    {{ form.profile_password.password2 }}<br>
         {% for error in form.profile_password.password2.errors  %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
         {% endfor %}
    {{ form.profile_password.sub_pass() }}</p>
  </div>

  <div> 
    Notes: <br>     
    {{ form.profile_notes.notes }}
    {{ form.profile_notes.sub_info }}
  </div>

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

So the problem is that I want to have separate validators for each part of that big form.

But this code

```
if form.profile_password.sub_pass.data and form.profile_password.validate(form)
```

doesn't return True, works only one part of this condition.

If "Save" button is submitted only validators for Notes should be run and vise versa for button 'Change'.

What I'm doing wrong?

jfyi:

I know that I can use multiply views to manage multiply forms, but I'm interested in subforms.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the **form** field of **profile_password**. So, the correct if statement should be:

```
if form.profile_password.form.sub_pass.data and form.profile_password.validate(form)
```